# Do not show autosuggest when list is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hey guys I need your help. I added a hidden list to a input search field. The list opens when you click into the input field and closes when you click anywhere else besides the list. For instance if you click on "Montego Bay" it will be added to the input field and also replaces the current text in that field.

However, I have two questions:

1. I have also a Google maps autosuggestion working inside the search field. How can I allow the Google autosuggestion only to pop up in the
   search field if my hidden list is not active?

The Google autosuggest script is:

```js
$(function() { google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,"load",function(){new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById("HotelsPlacesEan"))}); }); var loading = false;
```

2. How can I hide the list if its looses focus? (If I set

```js
$(".input").on("focusout", function() {
  $(".suggest-content").addClass("hiddd");
})
```

,the list does not add the text to the search field when I click on
it, but instead closes the list before it gets added.

Input:

```
<input required id="HotelsPlacesEan" name="city" type="search" class="form input-lg RTL search-location deleteoutline opensuggest" placeholder="<?php echo trans('026'); ?>" value="<?php echo $themeData->selectedCity; ?>" required />
```

List:

```
<div class="suggest-div">
         <span class="suggest-content hiddd">
            <ul class="liststyle">
               <li class="whylist"><b>Popular Destinations</b></li>
               <li class="suggest"><a class="selectlink" href="">Montego Bay</a></li>
               <li class="suggest"><a class="selectlink" href="">Negril</a></li>
               <li class="suggest"><a class="selectlink" href="">Ocho Rios</a></li>
               <li class="suggest"><a class="selectlink" href="">Kingston</a></li>
               <li class="suggest" style="border-bottom:0px;"><a class="selectlink" href="">Port Antonio</a></li>
            </ul>
         </span>
      </div>
```

CSS:

```
<style>

a.selectlink {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  display: block;
}

a.selectlink:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

ul.liststyle {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

li.whylist {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: #000;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 100;

}

li.suggest {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 100;
}

li.suggest:hover {
  background-color: #515B62;
  color: #fff;
}

.suggest-div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

span.suggest-content {
  display: block;
  background-color: #fff!important;
  margin-top: 0px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;

}

span.suggest-content:focus {

display: none; }

.hiddd {
  display: none!important;
}

.form {font-weight: 100!important;}
</style>
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".selectlink").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#HotelsPlacesEan").val($(this).text());
});

$(".opensuggest").click(function() {
    $(".suggest-content").toggleClass("hiddd");

});

$(".input").on("focusout", function() {
  $(".suggest-content").addClass("hiddd");
})

</script>
```

This is a screenshot of the google autosuggest over the list issue:

[image]

I would be very grateful if you would help me! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You talk about input search field, but not showing any in your html. You talk about google autocomplete popping up in your search field (= what you call the input element!!) So where does it really popup? In #HotelsPlacesEan? Where is it? Show all html markup needed. If you have a fiddle.. show it. As for question 2: the focusout fires before the click! One solution is to put the addClass line inside a timeout.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! I have totally forget to add the input, sorry. Have done it now! Maybe you can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: I can't help you without a working example, and without knowing the desired behavior. You say: when your "hidden list is not active"? That occurs when the input is not focused? Surely that's not when you want to show google results? Maybe you want to show the google suggestions, if your own script doesn't have any suggestions???

2: As suggested use a timeout so the suggestions remain clickable.

```
$("input").on("focusout", function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".suggest-content").addClass("hiddd");
  }, 250);
});
```

Other ways could be:

- instead of click, use the mousedown event which does fire on time. But you will have to check touch support
- delegated event: create a wrapper around the input and the dropdown, then on that wrapper listen for propagated focusout. The clicked suggestion will be the event target. From there you could do stuff like set the input value.

Here's a working example and some stuff to play with: https://jsfiddle.net/m3r72hnx/